# How many items can updated in a transaction in QLDB?

Tags: amazon-qldb

A transaction cannot contain more than 25 unique items - In a DynamoDB. 
Refer : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Limits.html#limits-dynamodb-transactions

What the QLDB limits on this? 
Also, does QLDB support across table transactions?

Comment: Maybe this link can help: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/qldb/latest/developerguide/limits.html

Comment: Thanks! It looks like it supports 4MB size on a transaction and doesn't explicity state item count limit. Just looking if QLDB supports cross table transactions as well :) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [limits page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/qldb/latest/developerguide/limits.html):

```
Number of documents in a transaction    40
```

QLDB transactions can operate across tables (but not across ledgers).